# Is there any way to call superclass's method on a subclass object without going through the subclass method of the same name?

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

If I have a superclass and subclass as follows

```
class Superclass {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("superclass called here");
    }
}
```

and

```
class Subclass extends Superclass {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("subclass called here");
    }
}
```

Suppose I have an object whose class is the subclass, say `Subclass sc = new Subclass();`. I know I can use `super.someMethod();` in the subclass's method to call the superclass's method. But is there any way I can call the supclass method on the object sc without having to go through the subclass method of the same name?

p.s. This question comes from a small assignment of UCB's Data Structure in Java course. 
Part four, question three.
[CS 61B Lab 5](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lab/lab5/readme)

Comment: Your question is not clear. `without having to go through the subclass method of the same name` - what does it mean ?

Comment: I think no one ever has thought of a valid use case for this, usually one designs a class hierarchy where methods are being designed explicitly to be overwritten.

Comment: If you find yourself calling `super.` methods often, you should probably stop and re-think your design.

Comment: @Rehman Sorry for the confusion. This is a small question from UCB's Data Structure in Java course's assignment, part four, question 3. [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lab/lab5/readme) In my understanding, it means not calling 'super.someMethod()' in the subclass's method's definition directly.

Answer (score 0):

No. Thats not possible. Furthermore, from the object-oriented point of view, ancestor classes should not know about their descendants, so if you need such thing, then maybe better to redesign your classes.

edit: maybe it is possible to implement using some classpath traversal and reflection, but I strongly not recommend doing it (see above).